# Scala: Ways of parent to child process communication

Tags: java, scala, serialization, ipc

I want to have one-way communication from a Scala parent process that spawns two child processes and passes some data to them. Then the child processes just read the data and do not communicate back again.

I looked into ways of serializing the data and writing it to temporary files for them to read, but it seems difficult because of its complex structure, circular dependencies and also they are in external libraries so its impossible to tweak the classes themselves or add type annotations that are used by some serialization libraries.

What would be ideal is to have some kind of C fork type behavior that copies the memory space. But from what I read this isn't possible in Scala, right?

Are there ways to achieve what I want to do without serializing the data? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using process rather than threads?

Comment: @Tim Because I want to have two `SparkContext`s and only one can exist per JVM. Two threads share the same jvm but two processes don't.

Comment: In my opinion serialization will be needed anyway, it's essential thing in jvm languages.